# LAN networking not working between Ubuntu Saucy and OSX Mavericks with iPhone Hotspot

Tags: macos, ubuntu, wireless-networking, home-networking, samba

At home, I have two machines (Ubuntu Saucy & OSX Mavericks) connected to my iPhone hotspot.  My iPhone is my gateway and I can access the internet from both machines.
Both machines are also able to resolve the IP address of the other when I use `ping hostname.local`.  However PING always returns:

```
"Destination Host Unreachable" when I ping OSX.local from Ubuntu, and 
"Request timeout for icmp_seq##" when I ping Ubuntu.local from the Mac
```

**SETTINGS**

Ubuntu:
I installed samba and it's dependencies using `sudo apt-get install samba samba-tools system-config-samba cifs-utils`. I have shared my user's `Public` folder without password.
I have UFW turned off. Ubuntu is connected to the iPhone via wireless (ip 172.20.10.3)

Mac:
I have enabled File Sharing for my user's `Public` folder with read access to everyone.
Other settings are default. OSX is connected to the iPhone through the USB (ip 172.20.10.2)

*OTHER*
On Ubuntu: in Nautilus' `Browse Network` window; I can see two icons for OSX(File Sharing), Ubuntu, and Windows Network.

On OSX:  I can't see anything in the `Network` folder (though I see `home` and `net` at the same level, and both are also empty)

When I double click the OSX(File Sharing) icon, I get a message 'Unable to access location'.

Any suggestions on what else I should do to enable file sharing between the two?

Cheers,
Nap

Answer (score -1):

Buy a wifi router, host a web-site on ubuntu (e.g nginx), make an html which contains url for the files you want to download, then just type 192.168.1.2 yyghjj

Comment: I'm not sure this qualifies as an answer, or even an attempt at an answer.  I've been burned too many times flagging things as "not an answer", so I'm stopping short of that.  But you earned the -1 for this not looking like an answer.

Comment: @killermist - You have been burned?  How exactly.  Unless your flags are being declined right and left you shouldn't worry about a declined flag.

Comment: @killermist - A post can be really weak but still technically be an answer.  Try flagging as "low quality".